# How can I implement the UITableView behavior/look for OSX?

Tags: macos, cocoa, uitableview, nstableview

In my app I'm trying to implement expandable drop-down table.

[image: general view]
general view

[image: expanded view]
expanded view

Does anyone have any hints on how I can make this?

Comment: why you want osx app looks like ios app?

Comment: I don't want it to look like iOS app...I simply need that particular interface that has a table(outer) with one column, where I can click on every row and it would expand down (like shown on the pic) showing another table (inner) that has N number of columns and rows...it just happened to be similar to UITableView...that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement like this way then use NSOutlineView

Comment: Also outlineview provide some datasource method for populating the data

Comment: Please follow this link http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/Displaying_Data_in_NSOutlineView

Comment: thank you...but, "sub-folders / children" in outline view don't look like a table row...I need to be able to have 5-6 columns with different data in them (image,string,number etc)